# how to split a line for each space and get each word in python

Tags: python-3.x

i got this error when i tried using this file as routable.txt as input

C  10.0.0.0  FastEthernet0/0

C  12.0.0.0  Serial0/1/0

R  13.0.0.0  12.0.0.2  Serial0/1/0

R  14.0.0.0  12.0.0.2  Serial0/1/0

R  15.0.0.0  12.0.0.2  Serial0/1/0

R  20.0.0.0  12.0.0.2  Serial0/1/0

R  25.0.0.0  12.0.0.2  Serial0/1/0

```
data=open('routable.txt')
data.seek(0)
for each_line in data:
    print (each_line,end=' ')
    (c_r, dip, via, eth)=each_line.split("  ", maxsplit=4)


data.close()
```

error is

C  10.0.0.0  FastEthernet0/0

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Python34/acnrouting.py", line 5, in 
    (c_r, dip, via, eth)=each_line.split("  ", maxsplit=4)
ValueError: need more than 3 values to unpack

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
with open('routable.txt') as data:
    for line in data:
        if not line:
            continue # skip empty lines
        print(line, end="")
        parts = line.split()
        if len(parts) == 4:
            c_r, dip, via, eth = parts
        elif len(parts) == 3:
            c_r, dip, eth = parts
        else:
            print("Bad Line!")
```

Notes:

- The `with` construct is the preferred python way of handling open files because it assures that the file handle will get closed when not in use.
- `data.seek(0)` is unnecessary.  When a file is opened, the file pointer is always at the start of the file.
- The sample input, as it appeared on stackoverflow, had blank (empty) lines.  An `if` statement was added to assure that these lines are ignored.
- Not all of your input lines had four elements.  Some had three.  This code tests for how many elements there were and unpacks appropriately.